# Fetch Single Item Using DataContext

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, datacontext

I'm doing the following:

```
public MyItem FetchSingleItem(int id)
{
  string query = "SELECT Something FROM Somewhere WHERE MyField = {0}";
  IEnumerable<MyItem> collection = this.ExecuteQuery<MyItem>(query, id);
  List<MyItem> list = collection.ToList<MyItem>();
  return list.Last<MyItem>();
}
```

It's not very elegant really and I was hoping there's something a little better to get a single item out using `DataContext`.  I'm extending from `DataContext` in my repository.  There's a valid reason why before you ask, but that's not the point in this question ;)

So, any better ways of doing this?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

If it is SQL Server, change your SQL to:

```
SELECT TOP 1 Something FROM Somewhere ...
```

Or alternatavely, change these lines

```
List<MyItem> list = collection.ToList<MyItem>();
return list.Last<MyItem>();
```

into this one:

```
return collection.First();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
myDataContext.MyItem.Where(item => item.MyField == id)
    .Select(item => item.Something)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Should be First(), I think, as his existing code throws when the list is empty.

Comment: I tought of this too, but assumed that he was using direct SQL for some good reason.

Comment: I mean that List<T>.Last() will throw. The SQL won't, I agree.

Comment: I need it in regular SQL unfortunately.  Requirement, not my choice, if I had the choice I'd do it in LINQ2SQL.

Comment: @Kezzer.  Ahh, bummer.  I'll leave this up cause elsewise you're likely to get another similar answer.

Answer (score 0):

The record returned is undefined, since you have no ORDER BY. So it's hard to do an exact translation. In general, though, reverse the order and take the First():

```
var q = from s in this.Somewhere
        where s.MyField == id
        orderby s.Something desc
        select s.Something;
return q.First();
```

Relational tables are unordered. So if you don't specify the record you want precisely, you must consider the returned record as randomly selected.